# Trying to make a graphing calculator, receiving Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, math, graph, stack-overflow

I'm trying to make something like [Desmos](http://desmos.com/calculator). I successfully made it plot some basic functions, such as e^x, sin (x), x^2, 1/x, etc. The problem is when I try to plot a function with another function as an argument. For example, I tried to plot sin (2x), and it showed me the aforementioned error, `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

I tried to do lots of things, but nothing worked. Here are the parts of code that are being used here: (some of it is in Serbian, but I'll translate what's necessary):

From the main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
/*...*/
Funkcija f1 = new LinearnaFunkcija(2, 0);
Funkcija f = new SinFunkcija();
/*...*/
}
```

From the `Funkcija` (function) class

```
public Double vrednost(Double arg)
{
    if(arg.isNaN() || arg == null || arg.isInfinite())
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    if (this.arg.equals(new LinearnaFunkcija(1,0)))
    {
        this.arg = null;
    }
    return vrednost(this.arg.vrednost(arg));
}
```

Note: "vrednost" means "value"

From the `LinearnaFunkcija` (linear function) class

```
public class LinearnaFunkcija extends Funkcija
{
    private double k;
    private double n;
    public LinearnaFunkcija(double k, double n)
    {
        this.k = k;
        this.n = n;
    }
    public LinearnaFunkcija(double arg)
    {
        this.k = 0;
        this.n = arg;
    }
    public Double vrednost(Double arg)
    {
        if(this.arg != null)
        {
            super.vrednost(arg);
        }
        return k * arg + n;
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

From the `SinFunkcija` (sine function) class

```
public Double vrednost(Double arg)
    {
        if(this.arg != null)
        {
            super.vrednost(arg);
        }
        return Math.sin(arg);
    }
```

The method that draws the function

```
public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    /*...*/
        Double xc, yc;
        int xp;
        int[] x = new int[1000010];
        int[] y = new int[1000010];
        int count = 0;
        for(xp = 0; xp < polje.getWidth(); xp++, count++)
        {
            xc = polje.getXValue(xp);
            yc = f.vrednost(xc);
            if(yc.isNaN() || yc.isInfinite() || polje.getYPos(yc) < 0)
            {
                g.drawPolyline(x, y, count);
                count = -1;
                continue;
            }
            x[count] = xp;
            y[count] = polje.getYPos(yc);   
        }
        g.drawPolyline(x, y, count);
    }
}
```

(Note: `polje` is an instance of a `JPanel` subclass)

So when I run that code, I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.newLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
    at funkcije.LinearnaFunkcija.vrednost(LinearnaFunkcija.java:26)
    at funkcije.Funkcija.vrednost(Funkcija.java:30)
    at funkcije.SinFunkcija.vrednost(SinFunkcija.java:42)
    at funkcije.Funkcija.vrednost(Funkcija.java:30)
    at funkcije.SinFunkcija.vrednost(SinFunkcija.java:42)
    at funkcije.Funkcija.vrednost(Funkcija.java:30)
    at funkcije.SinFunkcija.vrednost(SinFunkcija.java:42)
    at funkcije.Funkcija.vrednost(Funkcija.java:30)
    at funkcije.SinFunkcija.vrednost(SinFunkcija.java:42)
    at funkcije.Funkcija.vrednost(Funkcija.java:30)
```

, etc.

The window (`JFrame`) shows, but is completely blank.

Does anyone know what causes this problem? According to the error, the methods are apparently recursively calling each other, which would make a never-ending stack, i.e. a Stack Overflow. But that isn't supposed to be happening. Does someone else know what the problem is?

If you need more pieces of code, let me know.

Comment: You programmed a recursive function `vrednost` which doesn't hit its boundary condition before the virtual machine runs out of stack space.

Comment: Also, if the second `if` in `Funkcija` is `true`, `return vrednost(this.arg.vrednost(arg));` will **always** throw a `NullPointerException`, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a better design for `Function`, in which the recursive calls and calls to `super` could be avoided. It would be easier to reason about your code if the actual calculation logic (e.g. `return Math.sin(arg)` for `SinFunkcija`, `k * arg + n` for `LinearnaFunkcija` etc.) was separated from handling special cases and nested function calls.

One of the ways would be to apply the **template method pattern** like so:

```
public abstract class Function {

    private final Function nested;

    public Function(Function nested) {
        this.nested = nested; //a nested function, possibly null 
    }

    public void calculate(Double argument) {
        if (this.nested != null) { //first, try calculating the inner function
            argument = this.nested.calculate(argument);
        }
        if (argument == null || argument.isNaN() || argument.isInfinite()) { //then, check if argument is valid; be careful to check argument == null before you try and invoke methods on it! 
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        return calculateForValidValue(argument); //at this point, you're 100% sure arg is a valid Double
    }

    protected abstract Double calculateForValidValue(Double argument);
}
```

The child classes then become:

```
public class SinFunkcija extends Function {
    protected Double calculateForValidValue(Double argument) {
        return Math.sin(argument); //as simple as that
    }
}
```

You can nest functions by nesting the constructor calls: `new SinFunkcija(new LinearnaFunkcija(null, 2, 0)).calculate(3.0)`.

Note that the argument to the 'innermost' function is simply `null`. If you want to use the **null object pattern** (which I think is what the `this.arg.equals(new LinearnaFunkcija(1,0))` line was about), you could use a special `Noop` function:

```
public class Noop extends Function {
    public Noop() {
        super(null); //no nested function here
    }

    //this is the only case when we want to override calculate
    public void calculate(Double argument) {
        return argument; 
    }

    protected Double calculateForValidValue(Double value) { return null; }
}
```

You can then compose functions like so: `new SinFunkcija(new LinearnaFunkcija(new Noop(), 2, 0)).calculate(3.0)`, and skip the `if (this.nested != null) {` check in `Function`.

Comment: Note that if you *actually* want to write a tool akin to the one you've linked to, parsing user input is the difficult part. The above is just a warm-up :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I know that. Parsing will be extremely difficult, unless I require the user input to be very complicated.

Comment: Another thing: your solution would probably work, but why doesn't **this** one work?

Comment: Well, as @M.leRutte already pointed out, the recursion never ends. `SinFunkcija.vrednost()` calls `super.vrednost(arg)`, the line `return vrednost(this.arg.vrednost(arg))` inside `Funkcija.vrednost()` calls `SinFunkcija.vrednost()` again, and the cycle continues ad nauseam

Comment: But no: the line `return vrednost(this.arg.vrednost(arg))` will call `LinearnaFunkcija.vrednost()` which is supposed to return a number, more precisely `k * arg + n`, where `k==2` and `n==0`.

Comment: I strongly recommend to debug the code step by step, it will all become clear

Comment: Will try. Also, maybe I should reorganize the program according to your answer.